# Declare Class Attribute Protected or Public?

Tags: java, android, oop, class-design

I have a class say within a package com.practise.mypackageone.MyClass

Class MyClass has a method

```
 /* Modifier  */ void show()
{
 // some code here
}
```

I want this method to be only accessible from another package class say

com.practise.mypackagesecond.SecondClass

Now if I made the method public it will accessible to everywhere which I dont want.
and if I made it protected then SecondClass has to extend MyClass in order to access it.

But any other package class can also extend my class to access that method.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: not possible ...........................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the classes in the same package and make the method package private(the default modifier). Otherwise I think what you want is not achievable.

Comment: @peter thank you for your reply.. i am aware of default modifier.. question is make it accessible for other specific package.
For example i am developing a library which will comprise of few packages itself. the client code that will use that library should not be allowed to use some specific method my library packages are allowed to use.

Comment: This is not possible. The only solution is what I wrote in my answer but the classes have to be in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

The classes in the 1st package can extend a class from the 2nd package that looks like this, and they can implement the show() method as they wish:

```
    public static abstract class Showable {
        abstract protected void show();
    }
```

If there is only one class in the 2nd package (say, ViewManager) that needs to call this method you might want to embed this Showable in it so that only this class can call the show() method.

It is not a very clean design though.

Comment: even if first class extend this and provide a specific body. even then other classes can extend the first class and still can access the method.

Comment: There are other ways to prevent this. Make your class final, or make the constructor "package private" and use a factory to instantiate it.

Comment: if class is declared final then no different package class can access that method if declared protected.. hmmm

Comment: @Javanator We are mixing different things together here. Problem number 1 is to expose a method to a specific package/class. Problem number 2 is to avoid accessing a protected method by extending the class.